# os.listdir returns missing directory when filenames are unicode

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode

I'm trying to look into a subdirectory to obtain all unicode filenames in App Engine, but it gives me this instead. It works, however, when the subdirectory is filled with non-unicode filenames.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~theonlyrt6/1.372787192964623739/main.py", line 69, in get
    'titles' : os.listdir("./Articles")
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Articles'
```

This is my code:

```
        template_values = {
            'titles' : os.listdir("./Articles")
            }
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('HTML/Articles.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

The sub-directory is not uploaded as a static directory and it works when run locally.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your reference to unicode here. Where is the unicode in your example?

Comment: Things to check include - case , in appengine file operations are case sensitive.  second, templates need to be uploaded as code, not static resources, unless you enable a specific option in app.yaml.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The directory "Articles" contains files with Unicode filenames and data.

Comment: @TimHoffman The cases are correct, and that directory is not uploaded as static.

Comment: @TimHoffman I think the problem lies with the directory containing Unicode filenames and data? Everything works when the same directory contains only ASCII filenames and data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example [jinja app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-python/tree/part5-templates), the html files appears to uploaded automatically.